# Glide not loading image without placeholder

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide

I'm trying to load an image using Glide:

```
case "image":
    Log.d("TRecyViewAdapter", "Got Image");
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new    GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    ));
    contents.addView(imageView);
    Glide.with(context).load(part.getContent()).into(imageView);
    break;
```

It's showing nothing.

However if I change that last line to Picasso:

```
    Picasso.with(context).load(part.getContent()).into(imageView);
```

Image loads at full size just as I was expecting.

Also. If I use Glide with a placeholder:

```
    Glide.with(context).load(part.getContent()).placeholder(R.mipmap.def_avatar).into(imageView);
```

It loads the image but in a very small size (the size of R.mipmap.def_avatar)

I want to be able to load the real size image without having to specify placeholders (its a dynamic view and its supposed to show a lot of different images with different sizes and so)

I want to use Glide instead of Picasso because I want support for animated gifs.

Comment: I forgot to say that the image is loading from the internet. It's not a local image.

Comment: may be because of you adding view dynamically. try to set fix height and width of `ImageView`

Comment: Yep, looks like adding adding a fixed size shows the image. The thing is I can't know beforehand how big the image is going to be.

Comment: You should use `ImageView` from `xml` and second thing contents is `RelaiveLayout` or What?

Comment: I can't do if from xml, the parent (contents) is a LinearLayout and I have no idea how many ImageViews or TextViews it will contain or the size of that images

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like adding override does the trick. Image is now loading as expected.

```
Glide.with(context).load(part.getContent()).override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL).into(imageView);
```

Comment: I have this behavior as well. Is this a bug or a feature? :D

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this issue for myself, having the following attributes set on my ImageView in the XML did the trick for me:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</FrameLayout>
```

For reference here is also my Android code:

```
public class MyCardViewHolder extends CardViewHolder {

    public MyCardViewHolder(View inflated) {
        super(inflated);
    }

    public void bind(MyCard card) {
        ImageView imageView = ((ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image));

        Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                .load(card.backgroundImageUrl())
                .into(imageView);
    }

}
```